# High Numbered Colspan HTML Tables alterable via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm having some trouble getting my Table and Colspans to work. I'm trying to create a grid that can be used as a calendar. Each 'table' can represent a working day period (8:30pm til 6pm).

In my design I seperated this into 38 columns, one for each 15 minute time span.

I've done this so that I can display non-overlapping events next to each other, and ones that conflict with an already 'used' cell, can be created on a new row within this table.

However, with 38 columns in my design, my colspans are not working.

My first row is set to be 19 and 19, so 50%.
My second row is set to be 38, so that's 100%.

Yet when IE is rendering this, it's displaying the first row as around a 30% / 70% split.

My HTML/CSS/Javascript is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setColSpan1(){
    var x=document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells
    x[0].colSpan="1"
    x[1].colSpan="37"
}

function setColSpan2(){
    var x=document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells
    x[0].colSpan="19"
    x[1].colSpan="19"
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<style>
.column {
    font-size: 1pt;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 10px;
}

.emptycolumn {
    font-size: 1pt;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 10px;
}
</style>
<table id="myTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100px">
<tr>
    <td colspan="19"><div id="1" class="column" onclick="alert('test');" title="lala test"></div></td>
    <td colspan="19"><div id="2" class="emptycolumn"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="38"><div id="3" class="column"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1"><div id="4" class="column"></div></td>
    <td colspan="24"><div id="5" class="emptycolumn"></div></td>
    <td colspan="13"><div id="6" class="column"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>

<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="setColSpan1()" value="Change colspan 1">
    <input type="button" onclick="setColSpan2()" value="Change colspan 2">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I started with tests originally of only 6 columns, and that seemed to work perfectly, but increasing my design to 38 has broken this.

Is my design wrong? How can I get this to work accurately? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't work because the browser can't calculate correctly **width** of your columns

you need to create first row with 38 columns (without colspan), then hide it  and in your functions work with next row (1st in your case)

e.g.:

```
document.getElementById('myTable').rows[1].cells
```

P.S.: id attribute: Specifies a unique id for an element.

Naming rules:

Must begin with a letter `A-Z` or `a-z`
Can be followed by: letters (`A-Za-z`), digits (`0-9`), hyphens (`-`), and underscores (`_`)
In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

and specify a DOCTYPE for your document

Comment: Thanks. I've created 38 rows, and specified a width of 1px for each one and that works. It's going to leave a lot of empty cells code in the html, but I guess that just can't be helped.

I forgot about the ID naming rules, this page was just a test one though, a proof of concept. Thanks for the help.